# Why is the diagonally dominant matrix always row diagonally dominant?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

Why is diagonally dominant matrix defined row diagonally dominant, that is, in each row the magnitude of the diagonal entry exceeds the sum of the magnitudes of all the other entries in the row, without column diagonally dominant?
Thank you.

Comment: A "column diagonally dominant" matrix is just a transposed "row diagonally dominant" matrix, no?